# For what type of signals group delay of a filter should be taken into account?

Tags: delay

[Here](https://blog.mide.com/hubfs/Blog-Images/Which%20Anti-alias%20Filter%20is%20Best/Slide12-1.jpg) is an example showing the effect of group delay for different type of filters. And here are some conclusions from the site:

> **Bessel:** Has essentially zero overshoot. That was one of the design objectives. Has the smallest delay.
>
> **Butterworth:** Overshoots about 16% of the transition. Has a larger delay.
>
> **Elliptical:** Overshoots 20%. (Note that different elliptical filters will have different overshoots). Has delay about the same as
>   the Butterworth but has a slightly different characteristic.

When it comes to group delay always a pulse input and output in time domain is given as an example of the side effects. And overshoot is given as an example to the group delay effect.

If the signal we are measuring is continuous voltage but not a pulse or discontinuous signal, are there also circumstances when group delay should be taken into account?

Let's say we have an analog voltage input coming from a transducer which is not pulse. We can sample this voltage signal through an anti-aliasing filter. In this case can there be any distortion in frequency domain(when we take FFT) depending on the filter type's group delay? In other words does the group delay corrupt frequency domain?

Comment: A small variation in group delay was pretty important for modems, back in the day. (Recalling the days when I worked on a 600 bps modem's 6-pole transmit and 10-pole receive filters.) Just one of many examples.

Comment: Bessel has not the "smallest delay" but the smallest delay variation over frequency.

Answer (score 0):

The long-haul telephone systems relied on FM modulation. Filter delay curves were big part of specifying the channel performance, with goal of preserving the SNR.